# Matching a set of digits in gsub but excluding a set of identical digits when preceded by a "/"sign

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub

## Problem

I'm working with a vector resembling the **vecA** created below:

```
vecA <- c("data2002", "valueA2002", "value2005", "indicator2008/2009",
          "something2011/12", "abc2011/14")
```

I would like to arrive at **vecB** that would be of the following format:

```
vecA <- c("data_2002", "valueA_2002", "value_2005", "indicator_2008/2009",
          "something_2011/12", "abc_2011/14")
```

In a word, there is an underscore`_` before the time series identifier, however oddly the latter may be constructed. The only common characteristics for the time series identifier is that *it starts with **20.*** There are no other common characteristics, the time series identifier may be:

- 2000Q1, **or**
- 2009/2011Q3

## Taken approach

I would like to make use of the `regex` pattern that would match the *20* and negative look behind that would avoid matching *20* twice. So for instance in the string:

- *indicator2002/2003*
  I would like to match, only the first set of digits, so I can get:
- *indicator**_**2002/2003*

### Code

I would start with:

```
gsub(pattern = "20", replacement = "_20",x = names(x))
```

but this would match all instances of *20*. So my idea was to make use of look aheads/behind on the lines of the regex [`20(?<!\\2)`](https://regex101.com/r/oV2hI6/1) where I could exclude certain things from the match.

Comment: You can switch from `gsub` to `sub`, and what you've tried will work.  `sub` stops replacing after the first occurrence of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We match one or more non-numeric elements (`\\D+`), capture it as a group (`(..)`) followed by a numeric regex lookahead (`(?=\\d)`) and replace with backreference (`\\1`) followed by `_`.

```
sub('(\\D+)(?=\\d)', '\\1_', vecA, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "data_2002"           "valueA_2002"         "value_2005"          "indicator_2008/2009" "something_2011/12"   "abc_2011/14"
```

Or without lookarounds, we use two capture groups.  The first one as we mentioned earlier followed by the second capture group that start with a number, and followed by one of more characters.  In the replacement, we used the two back-reference separated by `_`.

```
sub('(\\D+)(\\d.*)', '\\1_\\2', vecA)
```

If this needs to be more specific, i.e. to match only numbers that start with `20`

```
sub('(\\D+)(20.*)', '\\1_\\2', vecA)
```